# No wifi or bluetooth on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I have bought a raspberry pi zero w and performed the headless setup and used ssh to connect to my pc.But it does not detect the wifi interface and always gives 'No wireless interface found' when i use the bash command 'ifconfig -a'.I have tried many things like changing the wpa-supplicant file or network interface file but nothing works.Beside that my zero w is also correctly programmed as ' sudo cat /proc/device-tree/model' returns 'Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1'.The bluetooth is also not working.Can someone help me to solve this problem.Here is the output of 'lsmod' command.I thought it will be helpful the sort out the problem:

`fuse                   93037  3
spidev                  7220  0
cfg80211              542402  0
 rfkill                 21476  2 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            23253  1
snd_pcm                89686  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22428  1 snd_pcm
snd                    60154  5 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
i2c_bcm2835             6465  0 
spi_bcm2835             7456  0
w1_gpio                 4566  0
wire                   31600  1 w1_gpio
cn                      5687  1 wire
hwmon                  10505  1 wire
fixed                   3033  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3718  0
uio                    10006  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 6674  0
usb_f_ecm               7416  1
g_ether                 5037  0
usb_f_rndis            17908  2 g_ether
u_ether                12901  3 usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis
libcomposite           48212  3 usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis
dwc2                  128996  0
udc_core              38862 5usb_f_ecm,dwc2,u_ether,usb_f_rndis,libcomposite
ip_tables              12427  0
x_tables               22130  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  397455  22`

Comment: What operating system you are using? Does `sudo iw list` give you detailed information about the wifi device?

Comment: You "performed the headless setup" (whatever this may be) BUT how are you connected to the Pi - presumably by WiFi (or some other undisclosed method)?

Comment: Have you set your wifi country. If not, then rfkill will disable all radio interfaces. Take a look with ```rfkill list all``` in a command line window [don't think it needs sudo].

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue a month ago, searched everywhere but in the end, I just re-installed the operating system and everything worked without any issue.